# Have any actors had roles in both the DCEU and the MCU?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, casting, dc-extended-universe

The title basically says it all. Has any actor played in both the DC Extended Universe and the Marvel Cinematic Universe? Preferably not some extra. Upcoming movies also count.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At first, this question seemed too broad to me. [This list alone](http://metro.co.uk/2016/03/27/from-ben-affleck-to-ryan-reynolds-19-actors-whove-appeared-in-both-marvel-and-dc-comics-films-5778778/) contains 19 actors that were in both DC and Marvel productions.

However, it seems to focus on the **[Marvel Cinematic Universe](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe)** and the **[DC Extended Universe](http://dcextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/DC_Extended_Universe)**, and that's a smaller field. MCU still spans over more than 20 films and 5 TV shows, but it doesn't include anything Marvel-related prior to *Iron Man* (2008), and the DCEU only released 3 films so far and doesn't seem to include the DC-related TV shows (*for now*, anyway).

Therefore, the answer is ***Yes***, but I can only come up with *2 actors* that appeared in both universes:

## 1. [Ayelet Zurer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayelet_Zurer)

**DC Extended Universe**: Lara Lor-Van, [Man of Steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_of_Steel_(film)) (2013)

**Marvel Cinematic Universe**: Vanessa Marianna, [Daredevil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daredevil_(TV_series)) (2015)

## 2. [Adewale Akinnuoye-Agbaje](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adewale_Akinnuoye-Agbaje)

**DC Extended Universe**: Waylon Jones \ Killer Croc, [Suicide Squad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_Squad_(film)) (2016)

**Marvel Cinematic Universe**: Algrim the Strong \ Kurse, [Thor: The Dark World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor:_The_Dark_World) (2013)

*Additional entries:*

- Australian actor [**Callan Mulvey**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callan_Mulvey) was Jack Rollins in [Captain America: The Winter Soldier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_The_Winter_Soldier) (2014) and Anatoli Knyazev in [Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_v_Superman:_Dawn_of_Justice) (2016)
- Actor [**Scoot McNairy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoot_McNairy) played Wallace Keefe in [Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_v_Superman:_Dawn_of_Justice) (2016) and Jackson Norriss in the one-off short [All Hail the King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Hail_the_King) (2014) which technically belongs in the MCU

<sub>*[There could be more, though. It's a little hard to go over every actor that appeared on all the Marvel shows, and many of the upcoming films' casts aren't finalized yet.]*</sub>

Comment: Is there a reason that the last two actors are in a differently styled list than the first 2? Are they somehow less relevant or did you just want to set a sign of there probably being many more?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I just added them later, is all. [It might also be a little biased, TBH; I know the first 2 actors from other things, but don't know the last 2 that well and their roles seem minor.]

Comment: That list of 19 is missing Tao Okamoto, who was Mercy Graves in DC's Batman v Superman, and was also in one of the Wolverine spinoffs.

Comment: You might want to add Laurence Fishburne. Perry White in the DCEU - Man of Steel(2013) and Batman vs Superman: Dawn of Justice (2016); Bill Foster in the MCU - Ant-Man and The Wasp(2018).

Answer (score 3):

##### Asim Chaudhry

DCEU: Roger (Co-Worker) in *Wonder Woman 1984* (2020)

MCU: voiced and performed motion capture work for Teefs in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023)

##### Chukwudi Iwuji

DCEU: Clemson Murn in *Peacemaker* (2022)

> Who is later revealed to actually be "Ik Nobe Llok"

MCU: High Evolutionary in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023)

##### Daniela Melchior

DCEU: Ratcatcher 2 in *The Suicide Squad* (2021)

MCU: Ura in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023)

##### David Dastmalchian

DCEU: Polka-Dot Man in *The Suicide Squad* (2021)

MCU: Kurt in *Ant-Man* (2015), *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (2018). Voiced Veb in *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania* (2023)

##### Dee Bradley Baker

DCEU: voiced Sebastian in *The Suicide Squad* (2021), and Eagly in *Peacemaker* (2022)

MCU: voiced Morris in *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* (2021) and Blurp in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023)

##### Djimon Hounsou

DCEU: Shazam (the wizard) in  *Shazam!* (2019), *Black Adam* (2022), and *Shazam! Fury of the Gods* (2023)

MCU: Korath in *Guardians of the Galaxy* (2014) and *Captain Marvel* (2019)

##### Gerardo Davila

DCEU: General Vera in *The Suicide Squad* (2021)

MCU: Fitz-Gibbonok in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023)

##### Jennifer Holland

DCEU: Emilia Harcourt in *The Suicide Squad* (2021), *Peacemaker* (2022), *Black Adam* (2022), and *Shazam! Fury of the Gods* (2023)

MCU: Kwol in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023)

##### J.K. Simmons

DCEU: James Gordon in *Justice League* (2017) and *Zack Snyder's Justice League* (2021)

MCU: J. Jonah Jameson in *Spider-Man: Far From Home* (2019), and *Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021)

##### Laurence Fishburne

DCEU: Perry White in *Man of Steel* (2013) and *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice* (2016)

MCU: Bill Foster in *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (2018)

##### Michael Keaton

DCEU:  Bruce Wayne / Batman in *The Flash* (2023)

MCU: Adrian Toomes / Vulture in *Spider-Man: Homecoming* (2017)

##### Michael Rooker

DCEU: Savant in *The Suicide Squad* (2021)

MCU: Yondu Udonta in *Guardians of the Galaxy* (2014), *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* (2017), *The Guardians of the Galaxy Holiday Special* (voice, 2022), and *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023)

##### Mikaela Hoover

DCEU: Camila in *The Suicide Squad* (2021)

MCU: Nova Prime's Assistant in *Guardians of the Galaxy* (2014); voiced and performed motion capture work for Floor in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023)

##### Nathan Fillion

DCEU: T.D.K. / The Detachable Kid in *The Suicide Squad* (2021)

MCU: voiced Monstrous Inmate in *Guardians of the Galaxy* (2014); portrayed Master Karja in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023)

##### Pedro Pascal

DCEU: Max Lord in *Wonder Woman 1984* (2020).

MCU: [Reed Richards / Mr. Fantastic in *The Fantastic Four* (2025)](https://variety.com/2024/film/news/fantastic-four-cast-marvel-studios-1235875766/)

##### Randall Park

DCEU: Dr. Stephen Shin in *Aquaman* (2018)

MCU: Jimmy Woo in *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (2018), *WandaVision* (2021), and *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania* (2023)

##### Russell Crowe

DCEU: Jor-El in *Man of Steel* (2013)

MCU: Zeus in *Thor: Love and Thunder* (2022)

##### Sean Gunn

DCEU: Weasel and Calendar Man in *The Suicide Squad* (2021)

MCU: Kraglin and On-Set Rocket in *Guardians of the Galaxy* (2014), *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* (2017), *Avengers: Infinity War* (2018), *Avengers: Endgame* (2019), *Thor: Love and Thunder* (2022), *The Guardians of the Galaxy Holiday Special* (2022); Kraglin, On-Set Rocket, and Young Rocket voice in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023)

##### Steve Agee

DCEU: John Economos in *The Suicide Squad* (2021), *Peacemaker* (2022), and *Shazam! Fury of the Gods* (2023)

MCU: Gef in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* (2017)

##### Sylvester Stallone

DCEU: voiced Nanaue / King Shark in *The Suicide Squad* (2021)

MCU: Stakar Ogord in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* (2017) and *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023)

##### Taika Waititi

DCEU: Ratcatcher in *The Suicide Squad* (2021)

MCU: Korg in *Thor: Ragnarok* (2017), *Avengers: Endgame* (2019) and *Thor: Love and Thunder* (2022)

##### Willem Dafoe

DCEU: Nuidis Vulko in *Aquaman* (2018) and *Zack Snyder's Justice League* (2021)

MCU: Norman Osborn / Green Goblin in *Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021)

##### Yahya Abdul-Mateen II

DCEU: Black Manta / David Kane in *Aquaman* (2018) and *Aquaman and the Lost Kingdom* (2023)

MCU: Simon Williams / Wonder Man in [*Wonder Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Man_(TV_series)) (release date TBA)

##### Zachary Levi

DCEU: Shazam in *Shazam!* (2019) and *Shazam! Fury of the Gods* (2023)

MCU: Fandral in *Thor: The Dark World* (2013) and *Thor: Ragnarok* (2017)